# Windows software for creating HDR images?

Tags: software-rec, images, photos, processing, hdr

What is the best software (free/paid) available for creating HDR images?

Comment: See also: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/3996/21

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had awesome results with [Photomatrix from HDRSoft](http://www.hdrsoft.com/download.html).

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2):

my first choice: **[FDR Tools](http://www.fdrtools.com/front_e.php)** ... amazing stuff!

*the Basic version is free, the Advanced version and the Photoshop plugin cost €39 each (€59 bundled)*

Answer (score 1):

Huge tutorial here at [Gizmodo- create-stunningly-realistic-high-dynamic-range-photographs](http://i.gizmodo.com/5168454/how-to-create-stunningly-realistic-high-dynamic-range-photographs). Based on Photoshop, but I'm sure that there's be some useful tips and techniques in there for any software.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Photomatix](http://www.hdrsoft.com/download.html) to great success, although it is not cheap.

Answer (score 1):

[Hugin](http://hugin.sourceforge.net/) is a free tool that can create HDR images. It can also stitch pictures together to obtain a panorama.

Answer (score 0):

[Luminance HDR](http://qtpfsgui.sourceforge.net/) is open source.